# Hugo Data Templates: Where to create files and what to put in them?

Tags: json, hugo

I have a Hugo SSG website.

My JSON file is saved in: `/data/source.json`

I created a template file: `/layouts/test.html` that has this content:

```
<!-- Data is in /data/source.json -->
{{ range .Site.Data.source }}
{{ range .names }}
<!-- person_name -->
<p>{{ .identifier.person_name }}</p>
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

How do I render this .html content to the website?

The Hugo documentation [here](https://gohugo.io/templates/data-templates/) doesn't explain what I need to do after making the .html file.

Comment: The question you need to ask is where exactly do you want to render that data? For instance, let's say you only have a single-page website, you can use that code snippet in `layouts/index.html`. Not sure if `/layouts/test.html` makes sense, as that's not a template Hugo looks for. Check out the lookup list here: https://gohugo.io/templates/lookup-order/

Comment: I want to render it on its own webpage. I have 10 JSON files and each file should render a page for its contents. At the moment, i cannot render even 1 page.

Comment: Do you have a theme installed and enabled? My first guess is that if no pages are rendered, then it's a theme issue. As Andrei says, you should rename `layouts/test.html` to `layouts/index.html` inside the theme directory. That is a file naming pattern that Hugo uses by default. If you have a shared theme, then I would look for `layouts/_default/baseof.html` as another place to find a top-level page that you should try to get to render first.

Comment: @BrianWagner only the test.html page is not rendering. The homepage and other pages render fine.

Comment: Ah ok. Have you tried moving that snippet into one of the templates that is rendering, like layouts/_default/list.html or layouts/_default/single.html? (If you want a page on your site with the path /test.html, you would create that in `content/` not the layouts.) In your snippet, you are only iterating over the data but not rendering anything. Also `range` needs an `end` tag as well. If you show more of the code you're using it will be easier to provide guidance.

Comment: @BrianWagner I added some more code showing the rendering now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two `range` operations when you need only one. You are not ranging over multiple source.json files, correct?

Assuming you have a file `data/source.json` like this:

```
{
  "names": [
    {
      "identifier": {
        "person_name": "Joe Wilson"
      }
    },
    {
      "identifier": {
        "person_name": "Nancy Wilson"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then it should be possible to render those names like this:

```
  {{ range .Site.Data.source.names }}
    <p>{{ .identifier.person_name }}</p>
  {{ end }}
```

Add that to a layout in your `themes/{theme-name}/layouts` and it will render on the pages using that template.