# Hugo static site generator doesn't render data template

Tags: hugo, static-site-generation

I am trying to display list of users, which is saved in `data/staff.json`

```
[
{
    "name":"John",
    "email": "john@example.com" 
},
{
    "name":"Ringo",
    "email": "ringo@example.com" 
}
```

]

This data suppose to be displayed in `content/posts/staff.md`

```
{{ range .Site.Data.staff }}
<h2>{{ .name }}</h2>
<p>{{ .email }}</p>
{{end}}
```

But from some reason All I can see is [unrendered code](https://sovfl.pages.dev/posts/staff/)

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDkGg.png)

I reproduced the problem [on live demo](https://sovfl.pages.dev/posts/staff/) and this is my [source code on Github](https://github.com/xnekv03/sovfl)

Any idea why I cannot loop through list and render?
Hugo version 0.100.1 (latest)

Comment: This block should be placed in a layout file, not a content file. What theme are you using? Is it your own, or a starter theme? Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72319522/hugo-data-templates-where-to-create-files-and-what-to-put-in-them/

Comment: It Is papermod theme https://github.com/adityatelange/hugo-PaperMod

Comment: The docs for that theme describe creating overrides for layouts: https://github.com/adityatelange/hugo-PaperMod/wiki/FAQs#override-theme-template. I think you want the layouts/_default/single.html from the theme. Copy that into your own layouts folder, and insert that staff listing block somewhere in there.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Hugo docs](https://gohugo.io/templates/data-templates/#example-accessing-named-values-in-a-data-file)
You have to add a $ sign before accessing resource file

```
{{ range $.Site.Data.staff }}
<h2>{{ .name }}</h2>
<p>{{ .email }}</p>
{{end}}
```

Comment: Thank you, but still [doesn´t work](https://sovfl.pages.dev/posts/staff/)